# Laptop keeps disconnecting from wi-fi

Tags: wireless, drivers, hp

I have a HP Pavilion Sleekbook and I just put Ubuntu on it. I enjoy it, but my wifi keeps disconnecting itself whenever I am downloading anything bigger than 1GB. Please help! This is very frustrating and making me regret getting rid of Windows. If I can't resolve this I'm going to have to figure out a way to go back to Windows.

Comment: Can you go to Terminal and run lspci and see what kind of WiFi adapter you have? Just comment with the "Network Controller," it displays. I suspect that yours is a RealTek... I had similar issues on my Thinkpad which led me to replace the WLAN card. This MAY not be the case for you, but since I changed to an Intel 6200 series my connectivity has been rock solid. I interimly tried a USB adapter which also worked fine. BTW, I was able to get card that fit my machine on eBay very inexpensively (and it was easy to change out)...

Answer (score 0):

most likely you didn't put your connection on auto....
for example, if your wifi is called 'homeinternet', you can
go up to the wifi icon on the top and select 'auto homeinternet' by hovering over
'homeinternet'.